# How to use moment to find first monday 18 month ago

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am writing some javascript and came across moment library.I would like to use the moment to get the first Monday of 18 Month ago. How would I do it?

I know 18 months ago it is

```
 moment().subtract(18, 'months');
```

But how would I know the first Monday of that time.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: nearest monday or first monday after 18 months ago?

Comment: The first Monday in the month 18 months ago, or the closest Monday to a date that is 18 months ago?

Comment: It is first Monday in the month 18 months ago

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in one line.

`moment().subtract(18,'months').startOf('month').add(6 - moment().day("Monday").day() ,'days').startOf('week').day(1);`

Find the moment 18 months ago, get the start date of that month, add 6 days since in worst case the first of that month is a tuesday(results in a date which is in the week that includes the first monday) and then get the start of that week.

Voila, all in one line.

**1st edit:** corrected the calculation to be locale independent and always return a Monday and not beginning of week since that is locale dependent.

**2nd edit:** locales makes it a bit more complicated. Adding 6 days to a Monday with a locale where the week ends on Saturday will move into another week thus we need to adapt the algorithm to take the Monday week number into consideration, i.e. subtract `moment().day("Monday").day()` which gives the locale dependent week day number of a Monday(0 or 1). Changed in the code above.

Comment: This is the closest to the accepted answer imo as it uses no loops. But there are two problems. First this answer gets Sunday instead of Monday and second this won't work if the first day is a Monday (ex. August 2017). Use 5 days instead


Here it is fixed: 
`moment().subtract(18,'months').startOf('month').add(5,'days').startOf('week').day(1);`

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for pointing that out. Actually it is a bit more complicated. Moment.js has locale support and thus you have to consider what locale you use. By default it is 'en' which defines the start of the week on Sundays. But here in Sweden where I live we start weeks on Mondays and thus my example is correct with that locale. But by always selecting day(1) as in you example one will always get a Monday independent of locale. Corrected my answer.

Comment: Your second issue is also due to locale. But you mean August 2016, right? Since I expected to use "sv" where we start weeks on Mondays adding 6 days gives the Sunday which is still in same week(when weeks starts on Mondays) but in a locale where weeks starts on Sundays that is another week. Thus adding 5 days works with an locale where weeks starts on Sundays but if adding 5 method is used with a locale starting on Mondays it will fail for November 2016 for instance, see http://codepen.io/karl-petter/pen/BWmPeY

Comment: Oh considering you are from a different locale this seem right. Thanks again, helped me on related project

Answer (score 1):

cleaner and more reusable IMHO ;)

```
var monday = moment().day('Monday').weekday(); 

var searchFirstMonday = moment().subtract(18, 'months').startOf('month');

while (searchFirstMonday.weekday() !== monday){ 
  searchFirstMonday.add(1, 'day'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go back 18 months, get the first day of that month, then the Monday of that week, you'll get close:

```
moment().subtract(18, 'months').startOf('month').day(1)
```

To make sure the Monday is in the right month, you need to break that down a bit:

```
var month = moment().subtract(18, 'months');
var firstMonday = month.startOf('month').day(1);
if (firstMonday.month() != month.month()) {
  firstMonday = firstMonday.add(7, 'days');
}
```

Comment: This gives me _d: Mon Jun 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (AKDT)

Comment: var month = moment().subtract(15, 'months');
var firstMonday = month.startOf('month').day(1);

Sometimes returns the last month

Comment: it gives the monday of the week the moment belongs to: it could fall in the previous month

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to do the same without any libraries.
Not sure if this is the best way to do it :P

```
var now = new Date();

//Get year and month
var month = now.getMonth();
var year = now.getFullYear();

//Months to go back
var monthsIntoPast = 18;

//Day of week we're looking for
var firstWeekDay= 2;

//Loop for one week
for(var x = 0; x < 7; x++) {

    //Go back 18 months to first day + x of the month
    var past = new Date(year, month - monthsIntoPast, 2 + x);

    //First monday
    if(past.getDay() == firstWeekDay) {

        //First monday 18 months ago
        alert(past.toUTCString())
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var moment = require('moment');
date = moment().subtract(18, 'months').startOf('month');
```

First we get the the current date and subtract 18 months. Then we find the start of the month, which as of today is

```
_d: Tue Jul 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (AKDT),
```

So now we need to adjust for the next Monday. We get the current day of the week with date.day() which will give us a number between 0-7 with 0 being last Sunday and 7 being next Sunday. In this case, the first is on a Tuesday.

```
>date.day();
2
```

So we take the offset of the day of the week and subtract it from 8. Why 8 you say? Because if you count every number including 0 and 7 there are 8 numbers. (Think arrays)

```
//since it's not monday we add the offset
date = date.add(8-date.day(), 'days');
```

In your code you'd want to check if the First day returned actually IS a Monday so as to not get the second Monday of the month. So the whole thing might look like

```
date = moment().subtract(18, 'months').startOf('month');
if(date.day() > 1){ //check if it's Monday
  //since it's not monday we add the offset
  date = date.add(8-date.day(), 'days');  
}
```

returns

```
_d: Mon Jul 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (AKDT),
```

Comment: This will give bad output if the month starts with Monday e.g. June 2015. If you test it using `moment("2016-12-01", "DD/MM/YYYY")` the output will be `2015-06-08` instead of `2015-06-01`

Comment: I had if(date.day() > 0) meaning if greater than last Sunday. Changing this to 1 (for Monday) should fix the issue. I've updated the example. Please let me know if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You use the following code to get what you need:

```
// Subtract 18 months from the current date, then get the first day of the month
var date = moment().subtract(18, 'months').startOf('month');
// Get current month
var month = date.month();
// Get monday of the first week of the month
var firstMonday = moment(date).weekday(0);
// Check if the first day of the month is not Monday
// and first monday of first week is in the desired month
if( date.weekday() != 0 && firstMonday.month() != month ){
    // Add 1 week if needed
    firstMonday.add(1, 'weeks');
}
```

The example above consideres Monday as the first day of the week. If Monday is not the first day of the week (day with index 0), you can get the correct index using `moment.weekdays()`