# how to get starting date of the week of each month of the year using "moment"

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I used "moment" in my project.

I tried to get whole weeks starting date of the given year.

```
var weeksOfYear = moment("2018").weeks();
```

But it won't works.

I want following output.

[1,8,15,22,29,5,12,19,26,5,12,19,26,2,9,16,23,30,7,14,21,28,4,11,18,25,2,9,16,23,30,6,13,20,27,3,10,17,14,1,8,15,22,29,5,12,19,26,3,10,17,24];

if you compare above array with calendar then you will see that these are the starting date of the week of 2018.

Please tell me, how can i achieve it?

Comment: @ChrisG i know that. but i am asking about logic, how will i implement it.?

Comment: Start with step one. First google result for "momentjs find first monday": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777272/how-to-use-moment-to-find-first-monday-18-month-ago

Comment: and as you mentioned the logic i already did. i got 1,8,15,22,29
if i got 29 and add 7 in it then it will become 36.

Comment: I obviously meant "add 7 days to the DATE, using momentjs commands"

Comment: ok let me try..

Comment: @ChrisG i did it. if you don't want to suggest any suggestions, logic or idea then atlist don't write such negative comments.

Comment: If you don't want "negative" comments then don't post questions that don't belong on SO.

Comment: @chrisG i agree with you but if you read my question carefully, then you can see that i am just asking for logic not for code. anyway thanks, i will remember this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. Though I am sure that someone else will have a neater answer.

```
var yearInQuestion = 2018;
var setYear = moment().set('year', yearInQuestion);
var firstMonday = (setYear.startOf('year')).startOf('isoweek');

// NB - Monday of that week might have been in the previous year
if (firstMonday.year() < yearInQuestion) {
    firstMonday.add(7, 'days');
}

var datesArray = [];
while (firstMonday.year() === yearInQuestion) {
    datesArray.push(firstMonday.date());
    firstMonday.add(7, 'days');
} 

console.log(datesArray);
```

Comment: yes, it works. my solutions works only for year 2018, but your solution works for all years.

Comment: thanks for asking the question - I learned some things today :)